# Theme styles and scripts not printing

Tags: 8, theming

I'm having a problem in my `html.html.twig` file where the styles and scripts variables are not printing anything, and when I debug with dump:

```
{{ dump(styles) }}  
{{ dump(scripts) }}
```

Both variables are empty and **'NULL'** is returned.

Any suggestions on how to debug this further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those variables have been changed in beta16/RC1.

See [HTML template head, scripts, styles and scripts_bottom replaced with placeholder_token](https://www.drupal.org/node/2565021):

#### Before

```
{{ head }}
{{ styles }}
{{ scripts }}
{{ scripts_bottom }}
```

#### After

```
<head-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
<css-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
<js-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
<js-bottom-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
```

The markup should be stable now with RC1, but when you're having trouble with a custom template, always compare it with the core default markup in the module providing it and/or the classy theme.